# How can I switch between Docker machine and Docker for Mac?

Tags: docker

Prior to running

```
eval $(docker-machine env remote)
```

I was using docker for mac and had environment context for that. However, after running that command I am now pointing to the remote docker machine. I understand how to switch between different remotes and say a local docker machine, but it is not clear to me how to switch from a docker machine back to the docker for mac engine.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you can

```
eval "$(docker-machine env -u)"
```

which I found from the github issue [page](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/1659).